# What variables are needed in init file in order to run eww in emacs 24.5.1 for windows?

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows, eww

I'm using emacs on windows, output of "emacs-version" outputs

```
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570
```

I added the missing libxml2.dll, (downloaded from [ezwinports](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/)) in the emacs path to quiet emacs whining about the missing dlls. Trying to open websites results in three outcomes

***1.***

```
Opening TLS connection with `openssl s_client -connect www.wikipedia.org:443 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof'...failed  
Opening TLS connection to `www.wikipedia.org'...failed
error in process filter: url-http: Could not create connection to www.wikipedia.org:443
error in process filter: Could not create connection to www.wikipedia.org:443
```

and the website refuses to open

***2.***

```
error in process sentinel: Invalid date: Mon, 06 Mar 2130 20:55:03 GMT
```

website doesn't open, after some googling I dug up a [bug report](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2015-02/msg00176.html) with apparently the same bug which seem to have been patched in emacs 24.4 version

***3.***

I am able to connect to the websites, hyperlinks are alive, but the buttons (i.e. google search and etc) not working

**tl;dr**

1. Added missing dll's to run eww in emacs
2. Can't access most websites with the exception of google news
3. Buttons in websites like google (search) is not working

What other variables need to be tweaked to get eww running correctly? or is this normal?

Comment: It seems like when connecting to an HTTPS web site, your Emacs tries to use the external tool `openssl`, presumably because it doesn't have the GnuTLS DLLs. I [wrote a guide](http://xn--9dbdkw.se/diary/how_to_enable_GnuTLS_for_Emacs_24_on_Windows/index.en.html) for how to install those.

Comment: I was trying to point to gnutls-trustfiles following the guide, but the variables does not seem to exist, any suggestions?  @legoscia

Comment: You might have to type `M-x load-library RET gnutls` first.

Comment: Thank you @legoscia that did the trick!!! I wish I can vote this up more than once!!!